# Connection based communication and Datagram based communication

Tags: java, sockets, networking

**What is the difference between 'connection based communication' and 'Datagram based communication'?**

Though i have gone through [this](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/overview/networking.html) i am not clear.

Answer (score 1):

Connection-based protocols such as TCP give you reliability and ordering assurances. They let you know if the packets you are sending actually reached their destination through an acknowledgment arrangement with the recipient. If any packets in a sequence don't make it through, the sender can be asked to resend the missing ones.

Connectionless, datagram-based protocols such as UDP don't give you reliability or ordering guarantees, but because there's "less to do" in the protocol it can be faster. Another major difference is that datagram-based protocols can usually support a broadcast of packets where multiple recipients get the same data delivered to them. With something like TCP, that's not possible because it's inherently point-to-point.

The Wikipedia pages on [TCP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_Control_Protocol) and [UDP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_Datagram_Protocol) are pretty good sources for learning more about the details.

Comment: I would argue with all of that. There's no inherent about reliability and ordering in a connected protocol. Reliable UDP and unreliable connected protocols are both possible. What connection-based protocols give you is a point-to-point connection with an agreed start and a notified finish.

Comment: If I had added the word "can" before "give you reliability and ordering" in the first sentence then we'd be saying the same thing. I was using TCP as the most obvious and common example. But yes, what you say above is accurate. At its most basic level a connection-based protocol gives you nothing but a simple point-to-point session.